# Find path of k nodes with maximum sum in an undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Consider an undirected graph. Each node has an index and a value, meaning that there can be two or more nodes with the same value. Find the path of k nodes which has the maximum sum.

What's the best approach for this?

**Note: The same node cannot be in the path twice. (No going back)**

[image]

Comment: Is the graph always a tree, or can it have cycles?

Comment: Yes, it's an undirected graph, cycles are possible; however, you cannot include the same node twice into the path.

Comment: The problem is NP-hard (Hamiltonian path reduces to it).